# If $(a^x-b^x-c^x)(x-2)>0$ then (i) $a, b, c$ can be the lengths of the three sides of a triangle $ABC$; (ii) $ABC$ is a right angled triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Consider three real numbers $a\ge b\ge c>0$.If $\left(a^x-b^x - c^x \right) \left(x-2\right)>0$ for any rational number $x\neq 2$,show that
(i) $a, b $ and $c$  can be the lengths of the three sides of a triangle $ABC$;
(ii) $ABC$ is a right angled triangle.
I'm lost. I literally have no clue from where to start. This question came in M. Tech level entrance exam. To prove the two parts I need to show that (I) sum of the lengths any two sides is greater than the third side and (ii) to show a triangle is right angled I need to show that $a^2+b^2=c^2$.But unable to progress. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $x\ne 2$, a reasonable step is to analyze the cases $x> 2$ and $x<2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x > 2$, $a^x - b^x - c^x > 0$ and for any $x < 2$, $a^x - b^x - c^x < 0$. The continuity of the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = a^x - b^x - c^x$ implies that $f(2) = 0$, that is, $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$.

Also using the fact that $f(1) < 0$, can you take it from here?

Comment: $f(1)<0 \implies a<b+c$ hence the sum of two sides is greater than the third side. Hence the lengths can be sides of a triangle. Am I correct?